# Reading json data generated by hasoffers api through php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have problem reading JSON data generated by 'hasoffers' API.
    Here is the URL: [hasofferslink](https://api.hasoffers.com/Apiv3/json?NetworkId=vcm&Target=Affiliate_Offer&Method=findAll&api_key=6e5dc9a940a0bb0964ebf3c934f400752c74538eed1dc4289dfbbe7b845b132c)

The above url generates JSON data. In that JSON data, in "response.data", it has the actual data, which I need to process. I just want to read one by one and display it over a page. In data field it generates offer id number, which is becoming difficult to read the data. I mean the number changes. I do not know the number, it is getting generated by hasoffers. Now how do i read each and every value in "data" part and display it in my page.

Here is the javascript code which I was trying:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    

    $.get("https://api.hasoffers.com/Apiv3/json?NetworkId=vcm&Target=Affiliate_Offer&Method=findAll&api_key={API_KEY}", function(data, status){
        //var json = JSON.parse(data);

       alert("response: "+data.response.data["1578"].Offer.status); //mkyong
        console.log(data.response.data);
       // var js = JSON.stringify(data.response.data);
        //$("p").html(js);
        var Dat =[];
        Dat.push(data.response.data);
       // alert(Dat[0][1578].Offer.status);
        /*
        var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Dat.length; i++) {
    arr.push(Dat[i].);
}
        alert(Dat);
        */
    });

});//end of document ready function
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p>data.</p>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have included your (I assume) private api_key; shouldn't you keep that private?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a snippet? I suspect it isn't, since nothing in the script references the HTML (so just remove the snippet parts and format the the same as it already is). Also, your question is relatively confusing. IE what does this mean: "In data field it generates offer id number, which is becoming difficult to read the data?"

Comment: Ya I assume, that should be private. However, it doesn't matter. I would change my key anyways.

Comment: If you click the link I provided, the page generates json data.

Comment: data: {
28: {
Offer: {
id: "28",
name: "Faballey.com CPS - India",
description: " India's trendiest online fashion Shopping destination | Buy Women's handbags, shoes, jewelry, accessories & more @ FabAlley.com <br><br> <strong>Converts on:</strong> Sale<br><br> <strong>Conversion Flow:</strong><br> 1. User Makes a Purchase<br> 2. Sale Credited<br><br> Deeplinking - <font color="gree

Comment: Above there is data and inside there is number 28. How do I access the keys inside Offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (replace REDACTED with your actual API key):

```
<?php

$apiurl = 'https://api.hasoffers.com/Apiv3/json?NetworkId=vcm&Target=Affiliate_Offer&Method=findAll&api_key=REDACTED';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($apiurl), true);

foreach($data['response']['data'] as $dataline) {
 echo "Offer ID: {$dataline['Offer']['id']}, Offer name: {$dataline['Offer']['name']}\n";
}

?>
```

That gives me output like this:

```
Offer ID: 1578, Offer name: 1mg.com CPS - India
Offer ID: 448, Offer name: 888casino.com CPA - UK, CA, DE
Offer ID: 1706, Offer name: Ace2three.com Android CPI - India
Offer ID: 1408, Offer name: Ace2three.com CPS - India
Offer ID: 667, Offer name: Adda52.com CPL - India
```

You'll also have available $dataline['Offer']['description'], etc; all the field names being listed here:

http://developers.hasoffers.com/#/brand/model/Offer

So you can tweak the part inside the foreach() to give you whatever output you need.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out. I was using three inner for loops. But your answer was a killer. Thank you once again for your help.